# Querying JSON Nested Arrays with Linq, JSON.NET, C#

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

This post is an effort to ask a more direct question related to my other recent post ([Picking Out Simple Properties from Hierarchical JSON Part II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602932/picking-out-simple-properties-from-hierarchical-json-part-ii)):

Given nested JSON document, as such:

```
{
  "Array1": {
    "Array1A": [
      { "Item1": "1" },
      { "Item2": "2" },
      { "Item3": "3" }
    ],
    "Array1B": [
      { "Item1": "1" },
      { "Item2": "2" },
      { "Item3": "3" }
    ]
  },
  "Array2": {
    "Array2A": [
      { "Item1": "1" },
      { "Item2": "2" },
      { "Item3": "3" }
    ]
  },
  "Array3": {
    "Array3A": [
      { "Item1": "1" },
      { "Item2": "2" },
      { "Item3": "3" }
    ],
    "Array3B": [
      { "Item1": "1" },
      { "Item2": "2" },
      {
        "Array3B1": [
          { "Item1": "1" },
          { "Item2": "2" },
          { "Item3": "3" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Array3C": [
      { "Item1": "1" },
      { "Item2": "2" },
      { "Item3": "3" }
    ]
  }
}
```

(Note: Above was validated with JSLint.)

Notice that the JSON is dynamic--I do not know in advance how many arrays there will be or how deep the arrays will nest.

**Goal:**
My goal is to represent each array (that is, Array1, Array2, Array3, Array3A, Array3B, and Array3B1) in a `List<JObject>` object. Each item in the list will be a collection of JProperty objects containing that array's string properties. Because the List doesn't itself model hierarchical data, I would need to add a synthetic property to each `List<JObject>` item that references the parent of that array. Thus, the parent of Array1 is an empty string; Array2 is Array1, Array3 is Array2, Array3A is Array3, Array3B is Array3, and Array 3B1 is Array3B...

**Question:**
1. How can I use C# Linq to create a `List<JObject>` object that looks like this:

```
list[0]: 
{"Name":"Array1","Parent":""}

list[1]:
{"Name":"Array1A","Item1":"1","Item2":"2","Item3":"3","Parent":"Array1"}

list[2]:
{"Name":"Array1B","Item1":"1","Item2":"2","Item3":"3","Parent":"Array1"}

list[3]:
{"Name":"Array2","Parent":""}

list[4]:
{"Name":"Array2A","Item1":"1","Item2":"2","Item3":"3","Parent":"Array2"}

list[5]:
{"Name":"Array3","Parent":""}

list[6]:
{"Name":"Array3A","Item1":"1","Item2":"2","Item3":"3","Parent":"Array3"}

list[7]:
{"Name":"Array3B","Item1":"1","Item2":"2","Parent":"Array3"}

list[8]:
{"Name":"Array3B1","Item1":"1","Item2":"2","Item3":"3","Parent":"ArrayB"}

list[9]:
{"Name":"Array3C","Item1":"1","Item2":"2","Item3":"3","Parent":"Array3"}
```

Please note that:

- Each `List<JObject>` contains only string properties.
- At list[7], the JSON token after Item2 is missing because it's an array.    Instead, that item is expressed in list[8] with the correct parent reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
List<JObject> list = 
    JObject.Parse(json)
           .Descendants()
           .Where(jt => jt.Type == JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)jt).Value.HasValues)
           .Cast<JProperty>()
           .Select(prop =>
           {
               var obj = new JObject(new JProperty("Name", prop.Name));
               if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
               {
                   var items = prop.Value.Children<JObject>()
                                         .SelectMany(jo => jo.Properties())
                                         .Where(jp => jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.String);
                   obj.Add(items);
               }
               var parentName = prop.Ancestors()
                                    .Where(jt => jt.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                                    .Select(jt => ((JProperty)jt).Name)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
               obj.Add("Parent", parentName ?? "");
               return obj;
           })
           .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FMxzls

If you're not that familiar with [LINQ-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), here's how it breaks down:

1. Parse the json string into a JObject

   ```
   JObject.Parse(json)
   ```
2. From that JObject, get all of its descendant JTokens

   ```
          .Descendants()
   ```
3. Filter that list to only JProperties whose values have children

   ```
          .Where(jt => jt.Type == JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)jt).Value.HasValues)
   ```
4. Cast the JTokens to JProperties to make them easier to work with in the next step

   ```
          .Cast<JProperty>()
   ```
5. Now, for each JProperty we selected, transform it as follows:

   ```
          .Select(prop =>
          {
   ```
6. Create a new JObject and add the JProperty's name as the `Name` property of the new object

   ```
              var obj = new JObject(new JProperty("Name", prop.Name));
   ```
7. If the value of the JProperty is an array...

   ```
              if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
              {
   ```
8. Get all the direct children of the array which are JObjects

   ```
                  var items = prop.Value.Children<JObject>()
   ```
9. From those JObjects, get all the JProperties

   ```
                                        .SelectMany(jo => jo.Properties())
   ```
10. Filter those JProperties to include only the ones whose values are strings)

    ```
                                         .Where(jp => jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.String);
    ```
11. Add these item JProperties to the new JObject we created earlier

    ```
                    obj.Add(items);
                }
    ```
12. Next, find the first ancestor JProperty of the current JProperty and get its name

    ```
                var parentName = prop.Ancestors()
                                     .Where(jt => jt.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                                     .Select(jt => ((JProperty)jt).Name)
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
    ```
13. Add the parent name to the JObject we're are building; use an empty string if there was no parent

    ```
                obj.Add("Parent", parentName ?? "");
    ```
14. Continue with the next transform

    ```
                return obj;
            })
    ```
15. Lastly put all the JObjects we built into a list.

    ```
            .ToList();
    ```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'm new to Linq so aside from the helpful breakdown of your processing logic, I enjoyed learning how to create variable within a select, how to use SelectMany, how to work with Ancestors(), and how to nest query logic within Linq. I am confident that this answer will prove to be phenomenally helpful to many other C#/JSON.NET/Linq developers...well done!